# how to rename GAM inputs at each for loop in R

Tags: r, gam

I'm trying to run multiple GAMs (generalized additive models) in R and convert their output summaries to a single dataframe. The data I'm running the GAMs on is formatted as one dataframe including many variable columns and one effect column. So, I want to create a for loop that runs a gam for each predictor vs. effect combination, then adds summary data (the r-squared and p value) and the predictor variable name to a new dataframe. However, I can't figure out how to rename the predictor column name within the GAM at each loop iteration without it throwing an error.

Example input_data:

```
Effect     Predictor 1     Predictor 2   Predictor 3
1            1                 4            4
4            2                 7            1
6            14                7            6
```

I want to be able to call the predictor column header at each loop iteration, then paste that name into the gam:

```
for (i in 2:4){

gam_predictor <- colnames(input_data[,i])
gam_output <-gam(Effect~s(gam_predictor, k = 4), data = input_data, method="REML")

}
```

However, I get this error:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Effect ~ 1 + gam_predictor, data = input_data,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'gam_predictor')

How can I get around this? I think it has something to do with the ~ operator but I can't figure out what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reformulate` to dynamically create your formula based on the column name stored in `gam_predictor`:

```r
gam_predictor <- "foo"

reformulate(paste0("s(", gam_predictor, ", k = 4)"), "Effect")
#> Effect ~ s(foo, k = 4)
```

And here a full working reproducible example using some fake random example data:

Note: I also fixed an issue with your assignment of the column name and made `gam_output` a `list`.

```r
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.9-0. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

# Create example data
set.seed(2)

input_data <- gamSim(1, n = 400, dist = "normal", scale = 2)
#> Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model

names(input_data)[1] <- "Effect"

gam_output <- list()
for (i in 2:4) {
  gam_predictor <- names(input_data)[i]
  gam_output[[gam_predictor]] <- gam(
    reformulate(paste0("s(", gam_predictor, ", k = 4)"), "Effect"),
    data = input_data, method = "REML"
  )
}

gam_output
#> $x0
#> 
#> Family: gaussian 
#> Link function: identity 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> Effect ~ s(x0, k = 4)
#> 
#> Estimated degrees of freedom:
#> 2.31  total = 3.31 
#> 
#> REML score: 1089.598     
#> 
#> $x1
#> 
#> Family: gaussian 
#> Link function: identity 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> Effect ~ s(x1, k = 4)
#> 
#> Estimated degrees of freedom:
#> 2.15  total = 3.15 
#> 
#> REML score: 1061.844     
#> 
#> $x2
#> 
#> Family: gaussian 
#> Link function: identity 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> Effect ~ s(x2, k = 4)
#> 
#> Estimated degrees of freedom:
#> 2.96  total = 3.96 
#> 
#> REML score: 999.68
```